# GitHub takes a long time to be loaded or gives Time out

Tags: github, github-pages, github-api

I dont know if its the relevant Tag to ask this question here but I m not getting into github website these days, Either it gives a time_out error in browser or page loads partially.There is no firewall setup or nothing that can make it happen so. I can browse any other sites very well. I want this from github - **seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/** But It always says -The server at seleniumhq.github.io is taking too long to respond. Even the github frontpage behaves the same way. Where can the problem lie? ( my internet speed is fast enough )

Comment: Are you still having this problem? If so, can you describe it in more detail -- I can access https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/ with no problem (apparently).

Comment: yup bro, why is it happening for this particular site? I need this API badly. In the past I used github a lot but I cant get in now. At first I thought Github might be down, but its working everywhere else. I always get " ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" ,  Is there any other way I can get that API

Comment: I still don't understand where you get this error. However, the API documentation is in the [SeleniumHQ/selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium) repository, under the [gh-pages](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/gh-pages) branch. I think you can clone or download the repository, checkout the gh-pages branch, and open what you need locally---it's just HTML and all files are there under docs/api.

Comment: Thats the problem, for some unknown reason github doesnt load on my browser( any of my browser) . I will try to use any site grabber to get that API. Can u plz get me the link that points to API for Selenium JAVA binding

Comment: The Java part is here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/gh-pages/docs/api/java. You can clone the repository (`git clone https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium`), then checkout the `gh-pages` (`git checkout gh-pages`), and go to `docs/api/java` or just open `docs/api/java/index.html`.

Comment: The problem is that I cant get to any of this page ... obnoxious !!

Comment: I found that I can see that API in browserling.com, I cant even browse that from my VirtualPC. I think something is blocking that site but not sure what ..

Comment: HELLO BRO, I managed to download the zip from the above. But I dont know how to open it up. Bcoz I cant download gitHub windows, is there any other way I can view the Java API in a browsing format

Comment: Sure, if you have the .zip for the gh-pages branch, you don't need Git, just unzip it and then open (double click or something) the docs/api/java/index.html file. Here's the link to the .zip for the gh-pages branch: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/archive/gh-pages.zip.

Comment: ohh man thats what I hv been trying to get for days, u made my day, Gracias bro ...   but I dont knw yet the reason for Github site's problem !!